# reconfigure vpn from cisco to juniper

Tags: vpn, cisco, routing

Right now I have a vpn from a cisco router (ASA 5505) with a network 192.168.1.0/24 connectiong to a Juniper firewall (SSG-520) with a network 192.168.100.16/28.

I want to reconfigure the subnet on the juniper side to be a /24.
I have changed all the interface settings and route on the juniper side, but the VPN disconnects after 90 seconds.

I am pretty sure that the problem is a route on the cisco side.  In the logs on the Cisco side it says "192.168.1.1   No translation group found for icmp src outside:192.168.100.1 dst inside:192.168.1.1 (type 8, code 0)"

Previously the Juniper was at the IP 192.168.100.30 (inside the /28 subnet).  Now it is at 192.168.100.1.

What is the proper way to recreate the route accross the VPN on the cisco side to make this work?